# map array to key value pair in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array:

```
    array (size=2)
      'filename' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string 'f1' (length=2)
          1 => string 'f2' (length=2)
      'url' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string 'u1' (length=2)
          1 => string 'u2' (length=2)
```

I want to map it like so:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'filename' => string 'f1' (length=2)
      'url' => string 'u1' (length=2)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'filename' => string 'f2' (length=2)
      'url' => string 'u2' (length=2)
```

How would I write such a map without knowing what the keys are called (filename and url). Would it also be possible for larger arrays?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
foreach ($startArray as $key1 => $value1) {
    foreach ($value1 as $key2 => $value2) {
        $endArray[$key2][$key1] = $value2;
    }
}
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work, the array I posted was a bit off. I removed the first line

Answer (score 0):

This solution will be flexible enough to deal with arrays of any size.

With your array as $startArray:

```
$result = array();
$counter = 0;
while ( count ( array_values($startArray)[0] ) < $counter - 1 ) {
    $result[] = add_array( $startArray, $counter );
    $counter++;
}
function add_array( $array, $index ) {
    $result = array();
    foreach ( $array as $array_key => $array_value ) {
        $result[$array_key] = $array_value[$index];
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: did you test this? It returns null

Comment: Edited the code to return the correct value. Should work now for PHP 5.4+